# Consultar estado de token y renovarlo, laravel 8

Tags: api, laravel-8, tokens

estoy trabajando con laravel8, estoy consumiendo una api (comercial) la cual me permite consultar data de unos clientes, el tema es que funciona bien hasta que el acces_token expira, cuando esto sucede tengo que ejecutar una ruta que me regenera ese acces_token, cambiarlo en la funcion que consulta los datos y ya vuelve a mostrar la data.

Lo que necesito es saber de que manera podria verificar si el access_token ya expiro, ejecutar esa funcion que renueva el token y poder utilizarlo

Hasta ahora tengo esta funcion para obtener el token en el controlador:

```
 public function get_token_autorizacion(){

        //Key Publica
        $api_key = 'ACA VA LA KEY PUBLICA DE LA API';

        //Url Base
        $url = "LA URL DE LA API";

        $cookieJar = new CookieJar();

        // Configurar las cookies en el array de opciones
        $header_opciones = [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'cookies' => $cookieJar, // Pasar la instancia de CookieJar como opción 'cookies'
        ];

        //Crear una instancia del cliente Guzzle y realizar la solicitud
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url.'/api/partner/token/'.$api_key, $header_opciones);
        // Si el status es 401 Significa para ir a buscar otro tojken
        // echo $response->getStatusCode(); // 200

        $data = $response->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($data->getContents());
        dd($content);

    }
```

y por ejemplo una de las funciones que tengo para consultar data:

```
 public function get_cat_vehiculos(){
          //Crear una instancia de CookieJar
       $cookieJar = new CookieJar();

       // Configurar las cookies en el array de opciones
       $options = [
           'headers' => [
               'X-PartnerToken' => 'ACA VA EL TOKEN QUE TENGO QUE IR RENOVANDO CUANDO EXPIRA',
               'Accept' => 'application/json',
           ],
           'cookies' => $cookieJar, // Pasar la instancia de CookieJar como opción 'cookies'
       ];

       // Crear una instancia del cliente Guzzle y realizar la solicitud
       $client = new Client();

       $categoria_vehiculos =  $client->request('GET', 'URL DE LA API', $options);

       $data = $categoria_vehiculos->getBody(); // '{"id": 1420053, "name": "guzzle", ...}'
       $content = json_decode($data->getContents());
       dd($content);
    }
```

Agradezco cualquier orientacion.

Saludos coridales